# How to set my default ruby version using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I installed Ruby 2.2.4 using RVM.

When I run `rvm list`, it seems ok:

```
   rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]
```

But when I try to run `rails server`, `bundle install` or anything else, this error occurs:

```
Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

To solve this problem, I run `rvm use 2.2.4` every time I open my terminal. When I do it everything works fine.

But I don't want to have to run that every time I need to do anything, and it is already my default RVM. I even tried `rvm --default use 2.2.4`, but it has not solved my problem.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

---

When I run `which ruby`:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby
```

When I run `rvm list`:

```
   rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: Open a new terminal and run `which ruby` and `rvm list` please.

Comment: no idea if this will make a difference but the rvm docs have the syntax different for setting a default version, with `--default` at the end. can you try `rvm use 2.2.4 --default` and then restarting your shell?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer @Uzbekjon

Comment: I get the same thing @sixty4bit

Comment: I see... So, rvm is using the right version! The problem is with `bundler`. Try doing `gem install bundler & bundle install`.

Comment: Copy the output of `rvm info` and paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability. Obviously something isn't right in your environment. I suspect it's a problem with your PATH, and `rvm info` will tell us. *How* did you install RVM? What directions did you follow?

Comment: @theTinMan I was already working in a 2.1.5 ruby project, I only used `rvm install 2.2.4` to get another version for another project. In fact, @Uzbekjon comment appeared to work here for me, I only run `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`.... I do not need to set my ruby version every time now. But isn`t bundler supposed to already be installed? Maybe I missed something during rvm configuration...

Comment: Bundler isn't tied to RVM. RVM only manages Ruby and gems, however unless another gem, such as Rails, is installed into a Ruby managed by RVM, and it explicitly requires Bundler, then Bundler won't be installed. Ruby doesn't install it by default and RVM doesn't care.

Comment: @theTinMan I see... But any ideia why everything worked fine when I used `rvm use 2.2.4` ?

Comment: You can set default Ruby with `rvm use 2.2.4 --default`. You can also pin Ruby version in the `Gemfile` as `ruby 2.2.4`.

Comment: I have no idea. You haven't given us enough information to do more than speculate.